install django in colab
I try to execute django server in colab but don't work
I write in colab:
!pip install django
!django-admin startproject portfolio
%cd portfolio/
modify setting.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['colab.research.google.com']
from google.colab.output import eval_js
print(eval_js("google.colab.kernel.proxyPort(8000)"))
!python manage.py runserver 8000
then I open chrome with print(eval_js("google.colab.kernel.proxyPort(8000)")) string
the browser show: error 403 That’s an error. That’s all we know.

Is there some evidence that running a Django server in Colab should work?

Not familiar with colab but what did you intend to achieve with !pip install django !django-admin startproject portfolio %cd portfolio/?

the web server seems don't start
